# How can I set the ToolTip for a TextBox when the cursor focuses on the TextBox?

Tags: asp.net

I want to set a tooltip for a TextBox In ASP.NET so that when the user focuses the cursor in the textbox, the tooltip is displayed. I don't want to set the typing text as the tooltip. I want to display my own message as the tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by using [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) - a plug-in used in conjunction with the  jQuery library.

UPDATE:

This plugin has been [updated to a new version](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/download).